# Adding filter to only one column metric in Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am new to Google Analytics API and am trying to recreate a report. I want 2 columns in my report, 1 with sessions and 1 with users. The session metric column that the report retrieves is the one I want to have a dimension filter applied to, while the user metrics to be as original. When I do apply I filter, it applies to all the metrics in the request. Is it possible to have the filter only be applied to one metric?

I tried applying the filters but understandably they apply to the entire request and the report I get is all filtered instead of just the one metric I want.

Comment: would you please add some more info including photos or codes to be clear about what you intend